# Taxonomy term in permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, taxonomy

I have a big problem. I have been banging my head on this all day long. It seems to be a stupid easy question. Possibly also with a stupid easy answer. But I can't seem to find it.

What I want is simple. I have a custom_post_type called "producten" and a taxonomy called "producten_categorie". Inside there I have got some couple hundred products that are all assigned to a "produten_categorie" term. I want to change the permalinks so they display the taxonomy term in the product permalink.

**What I have now is as follows:**

- www.domain.com/producten/ (producten archive)
- www.domain.com/producten/category (producten category archive)
- www.domain.com/producten/category/subcategory (producten subcategory archive)
- www.domain.com/producten/post_tile (single page for post in "producten")

**What I want is the following:**

- www.domain.com/producten/ (producten archive)
- www.domain.com/producten/category (producten category archive)
- www.domain.com/producten/category/subcategory (producten subcategory archive)
- www.domain.com/producten/category/post_tile (single page for post in main category)
- www.domain.com/producten/category/subcategory/post_tile (single page for post in sub category)

I can't get it to work. I first tried the "custom post type permalinks" plugin. Which did not work and gave me 404 errors. Even after flushing the permalinks more than a few times.

After that I tried manually changing the permalink by using ["filter_post_type_link"](http://www.webdesignerforum.co.uk/topic/46579-wordpress-rewrite-hell/page__view__findpost__p__294237). But I just can't get it to work.

You can find my code for registering the post type on the taxonomy here -> http://pastebin.com/DMfA21qb

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post

[How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post types like base-name/parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types?rq=1)

Accompanied by:

[How to change permalink structure for custom post type and it's taxonomies?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/how-to-change-permalink-structure-for-custom-post-type-and-its-taxonomies)

and

[Custom post types, taxonomies, and permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks)

It will cover what you are trying to do for /category/subcategory/othersubcategory/posttitle.

Edit: I implemented this and fixed some issues with a double trailing slash.
Look at this, it works [How to fix a double slash in custom permalinks with hierarchical taxonomy's?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75157/how-to-fix-a-double-slash-in-custom-permalinks-with-hierarchical-taxonomys)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a direct answer, but you could try the MagicFields plugin.
http://magicfields.org/

It makes working with custom post types and taxonomies a lot easier. I don't know if it is an overkill for your specific requirements though.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
'hierarchical' => false,
```

To

```
'hierarchical' => true,
```