# Custom post type category permalinks and archive pages

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

I know this question was brought up before, but I can't seem to get things working using any of the proposed solutions. This is how I have my custom post types and categories setup:

```
Custom Post Type: Buildings
-Buildings Categories:
--Medical
--Industrial
--Educational
--Recreational

-Buildings Regions (custom taxonomy):
--USA
---Connecticut
---New Jersey
---New York
--Canada
---Quebec
---Ontario
```

Every Building will be assigned to 1 building category (Medical, Industrial, etc) and 1 building region (USA->New York, Canada->Ontario, etc). This all works fine, except the permalinks to inner building pages are site.com/buildings/postname and there is no category archive for the custom post type categories. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Permalinks to inner building pages to be example.com/buildings/category/postname
2. Permalink to archive of all building pages to be example.com/buildings
3. Permalinks to archives of each building category example.com/buildings/category
4. Lastly I want to be able to display an archive of buildings by region. So example.com/buildings/region/usa would bring up all the buildings in the USA, while example.com/buildings/region/canada/quebec would bring up only buildings in Quebec, Canada.

I've tried numerous solutions, but the closest I was able to get was half of #1 working using the [WP Permastructure plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-permastructure/) posted as an answer to [this similar thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/adding-categories-to-custom-post-type-in-permalink). I am able to get the permalinks for inner building pages to generate properly, but when accessed they return 404s.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yev, without a code sample to work from I'm not sure how helpful I can be but I'll give you the code that I use for creating Custom Post Types with a archive page. This example will get you started for an FAQ (easily modified).

Note the rewrite lines and the flush, which is what creates a permalink structure for the Custom Post Types (and flushes the cache to activate it). I suspect this will get you fairly close to what you're hoping for but if not, submit your code and I'll try to help.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'new_cpt_faq' ) ) {
    function new_cpt_faq() {
        register_post_type( 'new_cpt_faq',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'FAQs', 'name_space'  ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'FAQ', 'name_space'  ),
                    'add_new' => __( 'Add New FAQ', 'name_space'  ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New FAQ', 'name_space'  ),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit FAQ', 'name_space'  ),
                    'new_item' => __( 'New FAQ', 'name_space'  ),
                    'all_items' => __( 'All FAQs', 'name_space'  ),
                    'view_item' => __( 'View FAQ', 'name_space'  ),
                    'search_items' => __( 'Search FAQs', 'name_space'  ),
                    'not_found' =>  __( 'No FAQs found', 'name_space'  ),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No FAQs found in Trash', 'name_space'  ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => '',
                    'menu_name' => __( 'FAQs', 'name_space'  )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
            'rewrite' => array(
                            'slug'=>'faqs',
                            'with_front'=> false,
                            'feed'=> true,
                            'pages'=> true
                        )
            )
        );

        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'new_cpt_faq' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'new_cpt_faq_taxonomy_categories' ) ) {
    function new_cpt_faq_taxonomy_categories() {
        register_taxonomy(
        'new_cpt_faq',
        'new_cpt_faq',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'FAQ Category', 'name_space'  ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New FAQ Category', 'name_space'  ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New FAQ Category', 'name_space' )
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'new_cpt_faq_taxonomy_categories' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How would you modify the code though to have archive pages for different FAQ categories?