# Add category base to URL in custom post type/taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am building an LMS type system in WordPress, controlled by `Custom Post types`.
The post type is called `Lessons` (with a slug of `courses`) and it has one `custom taxonomy` (category) called `courses`.

The domain URL structure shows right now as:

`domain.example/courses/lesson-name`.

I want it to become:

`domain.example/courses/[course-name{category}]/lesson-name`

or essentially:

`/[cpt]/%category%/%postname%/`

here is the plugin I wrote that is controlling the `CPTs` now.

```php
function rflms_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Lessons', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Lesson', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Product:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'New Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Lesson', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Lessions', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No Lessons Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Lessons Found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Referable Lessons', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'supports'        => array('premise-member-access', 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'),
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => null,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'courses'),
    );

    register_post_type( 'lessons', $args );

// Hook into the 'init' action

}
add_action( 'init', 'rflms_post_type', 0 );

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy()  {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Courses', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Course', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Courses', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Courses', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Course:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Course Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Course', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Courses with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Courses', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or Remove Courses', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from Most Used courses', 'text_domain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'courses'),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'course', 'lessons', $args );
}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Comment: Recently, I face this issue. **Solved!** [#188834][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy/188834#188834

Comment: **SOLUTION!** (After endless research)<br/><br/>you should modify the `post_type_link` filter. more at: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167992/33667 )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change permalink structure for custom post type and it's taxonomies?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/how-to-change-permalink-structure-for-custom-post-type-and-its-taxonomies)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Change your rewrite to add the course query var:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'courses/%course%')
```

Then filter `post_type_link` to insert the selected course into the permalink:

```
function wpa_course_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'course' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%course%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_course_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

There are also plugins like [Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) that can do this for you.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your swift answer. This makes complete sense. I'm curious though, where do I insert the filter post_type_link at? can i just go at the bottom of the entire document?

Comment: I added it to the bottom and it 404's the page.

Comment: you have to flush rewrites, visit the permalinks settings page.

Comment: also note you'll likely have a clash with a taxonomy and a post type both sharing the same slug.

Comment: Where i'm at now is it's making the permalinks right, but it's not executing correctly (it's soft 404ing). Any recommendations on what I can do to get this working right? I'm away of the permalink flush rewrites. Just click 'save' and it updates the file (it's nginx so it's controlled in the nginx.conf file)

Comment: Got it! It was a conflict.

Comment: Downvote - archive page 404

Comment: This doesn't work for translated posts on a multilingual site (for example using WPML).

Comment: This shows frontpage for me on the newly created URL. You gotta use the add_rewrite_rule() seen in @Floris's answer to make it work. Also note, archive pages stop working, I get 404 for /my-post-type and for /my-post-type/my-category

Comment: This will show the post no matter what the course slug is.  It shows them on ALL course slugs.  How to limit this to only show on the course slug that is selected and 404 on course that isn't selected for that person?

Answer (score 11):

The solution for me had three parts. In my case the post type is called `trainings`.

1. Add `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'trainings/%cat%')` to the `register_post_type` function.
2. Change the slug to have a dynamic category.
3. "Listen" to the new dynamic URL and load the appropriate template.

So here is how to change the permalink dynamically for a given post type. Add to `functions.php`:

```
function vx_soon_training_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $id );
    if ( is_object( $post ) ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'training_cat' );
        if ( $terms ) {
            return str_replace( '%cat%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link );
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'vx_soon_training_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

...and this is how to load the appropriate template on the new dynamic URL. Add to `functions.php`:

```
function archive_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^training/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=trainings&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    //flush_rewrite_rules(); // use only once
}

add_action( 'init', 'archive_rewrite_rules' );
```

Thats it! Remember to refresh the permalinks by saving the permalinks again in de backend. Or use the `flush_rewrite_rules()` function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the line where you have registered a custom post type using the `register_post_type` function.

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'courses/%cat%')`

To dynamically change the permalink of the post type, you have to add this code in `functions.php`:

```php
function change_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $id );
    if( $post->post_type == 'courses' )
    {
       if ( is_object( $post ) ) {
          $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, array('course') );
          if ( $terms ) {
             return str_replace( '%cat%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link );
         }
      }
    }
    return   $post_link ;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_link', 1, 3 );

//load the template on the new generated URL otherwise you will get 404's the page

function generated_rewrite_rules() {
   add_rewrite_rule(
       '^courses/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
       'index.php?post_type=courses&name=$matches[2]',
       'top'
   );
}
add_action( 'init', 'generated_rewrite_rules' );
```

After that, you need to flush the rewrite permalinks. Go to **wp-admin > Settings > permalinks** and update permalink settings then press the "Save Changes" button. It'll return URLs like this: `domain.example/courses/[course-name{category}]/lesson-name`

Comment: Down vote - 404 on both single CPT and CTP archive page types

Comment: @dev did you follow all steps which i have mentioned in my answer ? did you flush your rewrite permalinks? I have tested and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution!

To have hierarchical permalinks for custom post type install Custom Post Type Permalinks(https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin.

Update registered post type. I have post type name as help center

```
function help_centre_post_type(){
    register_post_type('helpcentre', array( 
        'labels'            =>  array(
            'name'          =>      __('Help Center'),
            'singular_name' =>      __('Help Center'),
            'all_items'     =>      __('View Posts'),
            'add_new'       =>      __('New Post'),
            'add_new_item'  =>      __('New Help Center'),
            'edit_item'     =>      __('Edit Help Center'),
            'view_item'     =>      __('View Help Center'),
            'search_items'  =>      __('Search Help Center'),
            'no_found'      =>      __('No Help Center Post Found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Help Center Post in Trash')
                                ),
        'public'            =>  true,
        'publicly_queryable'=>  true,
        'show_ui'           =>  true, 
        'query_var'         =>  true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' =>  false,
        'capability_type'   =>  'page',
        'hierarchical'      =>  true,
        'rewrite'=> [
            'slug' => 'help-center',
            "with_front" => false
        ],
        "cptp_permalink_structure" => "/%help_centre_category%/%post_id%-%postname%/",
        'menu_position'     =>  21,
        'supports'          =>  array('title','editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'has_archive'       =>  true
    ));
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'help_centre_post_type');
```

And here is registered taxonomy

```
function themes_taxonomy() {  
    register_taxonomy(  
        'help_centre_category',  
        'helpcentre',        
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Categories' ),
            'rewrite'=> [
                'slug' => 'help-center',
                "with_front" => false
            ],
            "cptp_permalink_structure" => "/%help_centre_category%/",
            'hierarchical'               => true,
            'public'                     => true,
            'show_ui'                    => true,
            'show_admin_column'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'query_var' => true
        ) 
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'themes_taxonomy');
```

This is line makes your permalink work

```
"cptp_permalink_structure" => "/%help_centre_category%/%post_id%-%postname%/",
```

you can remove `%post_id%` and can keep `/%help_centre_category%/%postname%/"`

Don't forget to flush permalinks from dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone interested in the solution, without having to tinker with raw PHP code, I highly recommend the plugin *[Permalink Manager Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/)* by Maciej Bis. It's a life saver.

It has a visual mechanism to remove or add whatever part you want in the custom post type's URL based on 'permastructs':

[image: Screenshot of Permalink Manager Lite]

(With all the pain involved in simple URL structuring with custom post types, we were about to give up on WP and move to another CMS. But this plugin in conjunction with ACF and CPTUI or Pods makes Wordpress fairly professional.)

Answer (score 0):

**Yep!** After a lot of research I got plugin **'[Custom Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/)'**. Which fulfils my requirement regards - custom URL e.g.

- for Category
- for Post
- for Custom Post
- for Custom Taxonomy
  etc.

Like this **Custom Post Type - Post**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me :

```
'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'portfolio',
        'with_front' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true // to display category/subcategroy
    ),
```

Comment: This does not make use of the categories or their path it only makes the custom post type hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `get_post_type_archive_link()`, maybe you will need to remove `/%cat%/` from the URL using `post_type_archive_link` filter.

Answer (score 0):

I found @chetan-vaghela 's answer almost perfect; in my use case I also wanted to be able to see a list of all posts by this post type like a typical archive page (i.e. /courses/, without any taxonomy after it).  I just had to add one additional rewrite rule as follows:

```
function generated_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^courses/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=courses&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
```