# Prepending %category% onto default posts fails

Tags: posts, categories, taxonomy

I have been attempting to change the rewrite slug on the default posts.

This is my post_type re-registering code (Taken from another post on StackOverflow) with the simple intent of changing the rewrite slug to include `%category%`

```
/**
 * Change the url structure only for default posts
 */
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1 );
function my_new_default_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'post', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public'  => true,
        '_builtin' => false, 
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( "slug" => "/articles/%category%"),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' )
    ) );
}
```

When I then view the slug when editing a post this shows as the slug:

[image]

These are all the attempts at getting the category into the URL and what the output was:

(%category% => `�tegory%`, %taxonomy% => `%taxonomy%`, %tax% => `%tax%`).

If I attempt to load the article I can put anything in the category section and it still (Incorrectly) loads

[image]

I've been reading through the taxonomies WP docs and other StackOverflow posts to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

**Important note**: If I put `/article/%category%/` in permalink structure it works fine except it prepends that to all my pages which I don't want.

**Note 2:**
I found this post:
[Add category base to url in custom post type/taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy)

The problem with it is that the article still loads even if you put anything in the category segment of the URL.

Comment: The correct solution is to enter it into the permalinks settings page, though I'm not sure what you mean by "it works fine except it prepends that to all my pages". The `post` permalink structure isn't involved in the `page` post type in any way. If you are seeing it in custom types and taxonomies, it's because you didn't set `with_front` to `false` when they are registered.

Comment: You are registering `post` as a post type and are doing it wrong. See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Reserved_Post_Types

Comment: As @Milo use your Settings/Permalinks page to set the structure you are trying to achive.

Comment: Maybe reading [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) enlight you about the difference between `Post(Post Type:'post')` and `Page(Post Type:'page')` . And yes as soon you add some in the Back-end, Settings/[Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) , it is for all **Posts**, but NOT for **Pages**. Last but not least, read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) also and then decide what(and how) you want to setup all. Maybe you will decide that a [`Custom Post Type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) could help you out?!

Comment: All makes so much more sense now. Thank you to Milo and all for your explanations. All working now that I've added with_front to my other CPTs and set the slug for posts in the permalink settings page. Thank you.