# Category base to url in custom post type/taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I'm building a recipe site that uses custom post types for recipes.
So I searched for including the custom post type categories in the url and found a solution below by Milo. It rewrites the url and adds the category. The only problem is; the archive page of the entire custom post type is now located at `/recept/%category%/`

**Solution Milo:**
[Add category base to url in custom post type/taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy?newreg=74c57a5381d1491c8ac4c1353a4e5f8a)

**Code being used:**

`'rewrite'              => array('slug' => 'recept/%category%','with_front' => false),`

```
function wpa_course_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
$post = get_post($id);  
if ( is_object( $post ) ){
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
    if( $terms ){
        return str_replace( '%category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        //return str_replace( 'recept/' , 'recept/'.$terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
    }
}
return $post_link;
```

I tried to delete the `%category%` from the slug rewrite and insert it through the function. But that breaks down all my category pages and the archive still won't work.

Comment: You must check your global `wp_rewrite` and make it sure there are no conflict rules.