# Creating custom post type relationships

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks

I want to create a custom post type relationships between two fields called 'Work' and 'Director' using Metabox. I have already created the CPTs.

This is an example of a permalink for 'Work' -> www.example.com/work/directors-cut-best-in-the-world/

This is an example of a permalink for 'Director' -> www.www.example.com/director/wes-pollitt/

What I want to achieve is where a director has one work in relation. So I want the permalink in this instance to change to www.example.com/director/wes-pollitt/directors-cut-best-in-the-world/ keeping the normal permalink for work as well.

Any ideas as to how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here, WordPress doesn't allow to run URL in two way.

```
e.g. (1) www.example.com/work/directors-cut-best-in-the-world/
     (2) www.example.com/director/wes-pollitt/directors-cut-best-in-the-world/
```

You should decide which URL do you want to run in browser.
If you want to run single URL then check this : [Add category base to url in custom post type/taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy)

You can conditionally change permalink before load.