# Custom Post Type Permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I need help with structuring permalink for the custom post type that I made. I think I tried all the answers here. I'm hoping somebody can help me.

**More Info**

The custom post is looks like this in my url `www.domain.com/oa/beauty/post-name`
but I want it to looks like this `www.domain.com/beauty/post-name/`
The `beauty` is an example of the category name.

The custom permalink structure in the setting is set as `/%category%/%postname%/` and I would like my custom posts' permalink to be the same format. If the custom posts' category is `health` then its permalink would be `localhost/health/post-title`. I used `post_type_link` filter to change the permalink.

[image]

In my custom post type I tried to rename the url and then saved it but when I visit it the permalink (url) is leading to 404. Even after re-saving the permalink in the settings, the problem still there.

This is how I setup and registered the custom post (in case I set the wrong arguments)

```
$args = array(
'labels'                => $labels,
'public'                => true,
'exclude_from_search'   => false,
'publicly_queryable'    => true,
'show_ui'               => true,
'show_in_menu'          => true, 
'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-star-filled',     
'query_var'             => true,                                              
'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'oa', 'with_front' => false),       
'capability_type'       => 'post',  
'has_archive'           => true,  
'hierarchical'          => false, 
'menu_position'         => 1,   
'supports'              => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
'taxonomies'            => array('category', 'post_tag'), 
'show_in_rest'          => true, 
'rest_base'             => 'oa-api',
'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
);
```

From what I researched, it seems that I should use `add_rewrite_rule` method. But I don't understand how rewrite works. Is this the right direction or am I missing something else?

I would like to solve this programmatically, not with a plugin.

Comment: Did you save permalink again from setting menu? Please try to save it and try to load page again?

Comment: Adding a category is fairly simple, you achieve it the same way you are removing the slug, however, you can't add a rewrite rule to support that structure because it already exists- it's the rule that captures parent/child pages. You will create a conflict between these two types, as WordPress has no way of knowing which you are requesting. This is why custom post types have a unique slug by default.

Comment: Your WordPress looking for a Page with the slug `health`.

Comment: @PunitPatel I have been saving permalink after after every code change just in case. And still nothing.

Comment: @Milo So you are saying is that I won't be able to remove custom post slug and that custom post slug is necessary if I want `/%category%/%postname%/`. Am I correct to assume that? So it will always be `custom-post/%category%/%postname%/`?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment so posting this as an "Answer".

A simple search will lead you to dozens of questions about this in stackoverflow itself, one of which is the following.

[Add category base to url in custom post type/taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy/#answer-94820)

Assuming you are trying to get the taxonomy term slug in the URL.

Comment: To add more info on what I need is that I wish that `%category%` would be dynamic. If the custom post's category is `beauty`, then I would like the permalink to be `www.domain.com/beauty/post-name/` rather than `www.domain.com/oa/beauty/post-name`. I tried that solution before. Basically I do not want the custom post slug anywhere in the permalink. But from what I researched, that seems impossible as of now and I might have to create rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment but I want to clarify something about Custom Post Types.
This is not an full answer so please edit it if I am wrong.

The Wordpress have it's own post which is the standard post.
It can be found here
[image]

And the Woocommerce have it's own custom post type which is product.
It can be found here if you download WooCommerce Plugin
[image]

So every advanced custom post type have thier own categories and tags as you can see in the images. So have you checked if you have the same menu type like your own category in your custom. Because if your own custom post type doesn't have it's own category and tag menu it will be hard to get the category you want fromt wordpress standard post. It's like you take a category from another post type or from a default post type.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have made it with 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

The best solution, with a simple regexp can read and detect all parameters in your URL and rewrite to show the correct post