# Remove custom post slug and add category to custom post type

Tags: slug

I am registering a custom post type through this function in a plugin. There is a problem that the end url of this post type has a slug. I want to remove that slug and replace it with the category of that post.

So there are two things I am trying to do.

1. Remove CPT slug.
2. Add CPT category to the URL.

e.g

www.abc.com/product/samsung-galaxy-note

should be

www.abc.com/custposttype-category/samsung-galaxy-note

How can I do this?

```
public static function register_cpt_aps_products() {
        $permalinks = get_aps_settings('permalinks');
        $slug = (isset($permalinks['product-slug'])) ? $permalinks['product-slug'] : '';

    // labels text for our post type aps-products
    $labels = array(
        // post type general name
        'name' => __( 'APS Products', 'aps-text' ),
        // post type singular name
        'singular_name' => __( 'APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => __( 'APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'APS Products', 'aps-text' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'archives' => __( 'APS Products Archives', 'aps-text' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search APS Products', 'aps-text' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into APS Product', 'aps-text' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'APS Product Image', 'aps-text' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set APS Product Image', 'aps-text' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove APS Product Image', 'aps-text' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as APS Product image', 'aps-text' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No APS Products found', 'aps-text' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No APS Products found in Trash', 'aps-text' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-products',
        'capability_type' => 'aps-products',
        'capabilities' => array(
           'read_post' => 'read_aps_product',
           'edit_post' => 'edit_aps_product',
           'edit_posts' => 'edit_aps_products',
           'delete_posts' => 'delete_aps_products',
           'create_posts' => 'create_aps_products',
           'publish_posts' => 'publish_aps_products',
           'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_aps_products',
           'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_aps_products',
           'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_aps_products',
           'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_aps_products',
           'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_aps_products',
           'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_private_aps_products',
           'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_aps_products'
        ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','aps-cats', 'aps-brands', 'aps-attributes', 'aps-filters', 'aps-rating-bars'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => 'aps-products',
        'supports' => array( 'publicize','title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'author', 'excerpt' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => array(__CLASS__, 'add_aps_products_metabox'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => $slug, 'with_front' => false)
    );

    $args = apply_filters('cpt_aps_products_args', $args);
    register_post_type( 'aps-products', $args );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add category base to url in custom post type/taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy)

Comment: I have tried following that answer. It is not working for me. 

1. I want to remove CPT slug. 
2. I want to add custom post type category in URL.

Comment: Hmm. Is `custom post type category` = `custom post type taxonomy`?

Comment: Yes, I think so: 'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','aps-cats', 'aps-brands', 'aps-attributes', 'aps-filters', 'aps-rating-bars'), 

I want aps-cats to appear as slug.

Comment: Take a look at this article, please http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks

Comment: I have taken  look and followed the tutorials in the attend the url is formed but it is not matching the write 'Matching Rewrite Rules'. How can I correct it? 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rookie Were you able to solve this problem? I'm looking for days to get this working. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use This...

```
function chapter_post_type_init() {
        $labels = array(
                'name' => 'Chapters',
                'singular_name' => 'Chapter',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Chapter',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Chapter',
                'new_item' => 'New Chapter',
                'all_items' => 'All Chapters',
                'view_item' => 'View Chapter',
                'search_items' => 'Search Chapters',
                'not_found' =>  'No chapters found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No chapters found in Trash',
                'parent_item_colon' => '',
                'menu_name' => 'Books'
        );

        $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'taxonomies'   => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/%category%','with_front' => false,'hierarchical' => true),
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'has_archive' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'menu_position' => 100,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt')
        );
        register_post_type( 'chapter', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'chapter_post_type_init' );


add_filter('post_type_link', 'book_permalink_structure', 10, 6);
function book_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%category%' ) ) {
        if( $book_type_term = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category' ) )
        {
            if($book_type_term[1]->parent == 0 ){
             $post_link = str_replace( '%category%', array_pop( $book_type_term )->slug, $post_link );              
            }else{
        $post_link = str_replace( '%category%', $book_type_term[0]->slug.'/'.$book_type_term[1]->slug, $post_link );
            }
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Comment: Your `post_type_link` function throws a bunch of warnings with debugging enabled. Also removing the post type slug this way breaks any parent/child pages of the `page` post type, causing them to 404.