# Permalink for CPT with taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

[**Edited**]

I changed the purpose of my site into an language learning site.

Now the CPT is setup as following:

**{ Language } - { Subject }**

- English speaking (slug: english-speaking )
- English writing (english-writing )
- English reading ( english-speaking )
- English writing (english-writing)

---

**Single CPT setup**

Because each CPT might have different taxonomy… so it is preferred this would be taking into consideration of the code.

Say: CPT “English Speaking” has a custom taxonomy of “Speaking Task” (speaking-task) with terms “task-1”, “task-2”, “task-3” … . But: CPT “English Writing” has no taxonomy at all.

Desired URL for single CPT post item:

**With custom taxonomy terms:**

- www.domain.com/{language}/{subject}/{ term-slug }/{custom-question-id}/{post-name}
- ex. www.domain.com/english/speaking/speaking-1/32/blah-blah-blah

**Without custom taxonomy terms:**

- www.domain.com/{language}/{subject}/{custom-question-id}/{post-name}
- ex. www.domain.com/english/writing/32/blah-blah-blah

**The URL rewrite part for Single CPT is not a problem for me now thanks to your teaching and genius code provided in the new answer**

What I am struggling with is the rewrite for the CPT Archive page below:

---

**CPT Archive setup**

I am trying to create a custom CPT Archive template with the following setup for URL:

- www.domain.com/ { language } / { subject } 
  ex. www.domain.com/english/speaking
- www.domain.com/ { language } / { subject } / { terms-slug }
- ex1. www.domain.com/english/speaking (instead of listing all posts, I wish to make it default to list out to “speaking-1”)
- ex2. www.domain.com/english/speaking/speaking-1   (only list out post under “speaking-1” )
- ex3. www.domain.com/english/speaking/speaking-2 (only list out post under “speaking-2” )

———————————————————————————————————

In [**archive-english-speaking.php**] , I have the following code:

```
// use add_rewrite_rule in funcitons; query_vars "task" is terms of speaking-task taxonomy
global $wp_query;
$task_no = $wp_query->query_vars['task'];


if (preg_match("/[1-6]/", $task_no)) {
  $task = ( 'speaking-' . $task_no );
} else {
  $task_no = ( '1' );
  $task = ( 'speaking-' . $task_no );
}

$posts_per_page = 10;


$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'english-speaking',
  'taxonomy' => 'speaking-task',
  'term' => $task,
  /*'paged' => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,*/
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key' => 'wpcf-question-id',
  'order'   => 'ASC', /* ASC/DESC */
   ) );
```

———————————————————————————————————

In [**functions.php**] , I have the following code:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    //taxonomy speaking-task =?
    add_rewrite_tag('%task%', '([^/]*)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);



// Custom Question ID from custom field
function cqid() {
    $cqid = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-question-id', true );
    return $cqid;
}


function my_questions_cpt_list() {
    return [
    // Format: POST_TYPE   => QUESTION_SUBJECT_SLUG
        'english-listening' => 'listening',
        'english-speaking' => 'speaking',
        'english-reading' => 'reading',
        'english-writing' => 'writing',
        // Add more items as needed, or if and when you register another CPT
        // for questions.
    ];
}


add_action( 'init', 'my_questions_cpt_add_rewrite_rules' );
function my_questions_cpt_add_rewrite_rules() {


// Archive Page 
add_rewrite_rule( '^english/speaking/?$','index.php?post_type=english-speaking&taxonomy=speaking-task&task=$matches[1]', 'top' );
add_rewrite_rule( '^english/speaking/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?post_type=english-speaking&taxonomy=speaking-task&task=$matches[1]', 'top' );


//
$cpt_list = my_questions_cpt_list();
foreach ( $cpt_list as $post_type => $q_subject ) {
    if ( empty( $post_type ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    if ( ! $s = preg_quote( $q_subject ) ) {
        continue;
    }


    add_rewrite_rule('^english/(' . $s . ')/(\d+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?','index.php?' . $post_type . '=$matches[4]','top');
}
}



add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_questions_cpt_custom_permalink', 10, 2 );
function my_questions_cpt_custom_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    $taxonomy = 'speaking-task';
    $cpt_list = my_questions_cpt_list();

if ( false === strpos( $permalink, '?' ) &&
$post && isset( $cpt_list[ $post->post_type ] ) ) {
    $cats = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy );
    if ( $cats && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ) {
        // If assigned to multiple tasks (or categories), then we use just
        // the first task/term.

        $cat_id = $cats[0]->slug; //term_id
        $task = $cat_id[strlen($cat_id)-1];
        $cqid = cqid();

        $s = $cpt_list[ $post->post_type ];
        $permalink = home_url( 'english/' . $s . '/' . $task . '/' . $cqid . '/' . $post->post_name . '/' );
        $permalink = user_trailingslashit( $permalink, 'single' );
    }
}

return $permalink;
}
```

———————————————————————————————————

@Sally
The code above is limited to my programming level, I used your first answer and modified it... it is kind working in localhost but the archive url got 404 or blank page when I moved it to online hosting server...

Comment: after some research, seems like I need to use "is_front", but I could not find a good example ...

Comment: Use [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94820/11761) as a starting point.

Comment: Could be done using a placeholder in `slug` argument in `rewrite` parameter while registering the post type. Then a str_replace in `post_type_link` filter or `add_rewrite_rule` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Updated/new answer)*

So here I'm going straight to the code you need: (but do read the updated version of the original answer)

### Register the CPT's and Set the proper *rewrite* `slug`

1. This is for the *"English Speaking" CPT*, which is assigned to the
   *custom taxonomy* "Speaking Task":

   ```
   register_post_type( 'english-speaking', array(
       'label' => 'English Speaking',
       'public' => true,
       'rewrite' => array(
           'slug' => 'english/speaking/%speaking_task%/%question_id%',
       ),
       // Other args here.
   ) );
   ```
2. This is for the *"English Writing" CPT*, which is *not* assigned to
   any taxonomy:

   ```
   register_post_type( 'english-writing', array(
       'label' => 'English Writing',
       'public' => true,
       'rewrite' => array(
           'slug' => 'english/writing/%question_id%',
       ),
       // Other args here.
   ) );
   ```

### Register the *custom taxonomy* "Speaking Task"

```
register_taxonomy( 'speaking-task', array( 'english-speaking' ), array(
    'label' => 'Speaking Tasks',
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'english/speaking',
    ),
    // Other args here.
) );
```

Make sure the *rewrite* `slug` is set to `english/speaking`.

The "English Speaking" *archive* would be accessible at:

- `http://example.com/english/speaking`
- `http://example.com/english/speaking/{SPEAKING TASK SLUG}`

### Register the *custom rewrite tags*

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%question_id%', '(\d+)' );
add_rewrite_tag( '%speaking_task%', '([^/]+)' );
```

### Add the code for *replacing* the custom rewrite tags

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_filter_questions_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
function my_filter_questions_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ) {
    // Replaces/rewrites %question_id% in the permalink.
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%question_id%' ) ) {
        $id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpcf-question-id', true );

        // A default value is necessary, and the value has to be a 0.
        $id = $id ? $id : '0';

        $post_link = str_replace( '%question_id%', $id, $post_link );
    }

    // Replaces/rewrites %speaking_task% in the permalink.
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%speaking_task%' ) ) {
        // A default value is necessary, but the term/category doesn't need to
        // actually exists. So you could, for example, use 'all' as the value.
        $slug = 'uncategorized';

        $cats = get_the_terms( $post, 'speaking-task' );
        if ( $cats && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ) {
            $slug = $cats[0]->slug;
        }

        $post_link = str_replace( '%speaking_task%', $slug, $post_link );
    }

    return $post_link;
}
```

### Flush the rewrite rules

*Refer to my other answer* if you don't know how to flush the rules..

### Use `get_query_var()` to retrieve the rewrite tag values

- `get_query_var( 'question_id' )` for `%question_id%`
- `get_query_var( 'task_slug' )` for `%task_slug%`

---

The *full* sample code [is available here](https://pastebin.com/qzEsixjj). :)

---

### UPDATE

If you use a plugin to register the **post type**, you can filter (set/change) the *rewrite* `slug` via the `register_post_type_args` filter, like so:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'my_filter_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function my_filter_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( ! isset( $args['rewrite'] ) ) {
        $args['rewrite'] = array();
    }

    if ( 'english-speaking' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'english/speaking/%speaking_task%/%question_id%';
    } elseif ( 'english-speaking' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'english/writing/%question_id%';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

And likewise if you use a plugin to register the **custom taxonomy**, you can filter (set/change) the *rewrite* `slug` via the `register_taxonomy_args` filter, like so:

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'my_filter_taxonomy_args', 10, 2 );
function my_filter_taxonomy_args( $args, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( ! isset( $args['rewrite'] ) ) {
        $args['rewrite'] = array();
    }

    if ( 'speaking-task' === $taxonomy ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'english/speaking';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

You might need to set a *lower priority* — i.e. change the `10` to `11` or a higher value (number) — greater number = lower priority, whereas lower number = higher priority.

*Alternatively, without custom coding,* and if the plugin allows you to manually set the rewrite slug of the custom post type or taxonomy, then just use the appropriate box/field to enter the appropriate rewrite slug. =)

Comment: Hello Sally, sorry for the late response. Thank you for the code and teaching, much much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please also teach me how to create a rewrite to a cpt archive page? 

====================
CPT: 

What I am trying to accomplished is to have URL like this:

Comment: Hi @Atimmy, your last comment seems incomplete.. can you re-post that, particularly after the "URL like this" part?

Comment: Hi Sally, 

I used your genius code and one tiny issue… (could be result of my minor modification )

The “$s “ seems to be reflecting the meta key value of “custom-question-id” instead of the “subject”. 

If I simply moved this line of code “$s = $cpt_list[ $post->post_type ];” out side the if statement, it then will reflect the subject....

Comment: I am going to edit my question now because the requirement has changed and my questions can not be fit into comment

Comment: So I've edited the original answer, and I'm going to edit this answer now to match the edited question. If you haven't tried the code solution in the other answer, it's alright. I'll be back once I've finished editing this answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please backup your `functions.php` file, then edit that file (well not the backup one): 1) remove all my codes you took from my other answer and/or the [first version](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/306993/1) of this answer; 2) follow *all* the steps in the new version of this answer - if you got stuck at any step/part, let me know. For the `archive-english-speaking.php`, **temporarily** rename it and let WordPress uses the default `archive.php` or `index.php` file to display posts on the "Speaking Task" archive page.

Comment: Hi Sally, thank you again for the code. The thing is that the CPT on my site is created through a plugin and i won't be able to directly edit the slug. Would it works if I use "register_post_type_args" to update the slug?

Comment: your code works, but as for my situation where the CPT was created through a plugin..... I've tried to use this to modify the CPT slug... but not working:

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpd_modify_post_type', 10, 2 );
function wpd_modify_post_type( $args, $post_type ){
    if( 'english-speaking' == $post_type ){
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'english/speaking/%speaking_task%/%question_id%';
    }
    return $args;
}

Comment: Hi @Atimmy, please check the updated answer. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

*(Updated/new answer)*

**For the [original](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/301239/1) question**

I changed my original answer because there's actually a *way simpler* solution (without having to use the `add_rewrite_rule()` function, or hooking to the `parse_request` filter) in achieving this permalink structure (for your "questions" CPT):

- `/{SLUG}/question/{TASK ID}/{POST SLUG}`

For example, you could have these permalinks:

- `/science/question/2/science-question-1`
- `/math/question/4/math-question-1`
- `/english/question/4/english-question-1`

**So how to achieve that?**

When you register a "question" CPT via the `register_post_type()` function, set the *rewrite* `slug` to `{SLUG}/question/%task_id%` where `{SLUG}` is *any* slug such as `science`, `math`, and `english`.

```
register_post_type( 'science-question', array(
    'label' => 'Science Questions',
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        // The rewrite slug. You can change 'science' to whatever you like.
        'slug' => 'science/question/%task_id%',
    ),
    // Other args here.
) );

register_post_type( 'math-question', array(
    'label' => 'Math Questions',
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        // The rewrite slug. You can change 'math' to whatever you like.
        'slug' => 'math/question/%task_id%',
    ),
    // Other args here.
) );
```

Then for the *custom taxonomy* "Task" (registered via the `register_taxonomy()` function), set the *taxonomy* **slug** to `task` like this example:

```
// Set the slug to 'task'.
register_taxonomy( 'task', array( '{POST TYPE}', '{POST TYPE}', ... ), array(
    'label' => 'Tasks',
    'public' => true,
    // Other args here.
) );
```

(The `{POST TYPE}` could be `science-question`, `math-question`, etc.)

Next, add this code which will register the *custom rewrite tag* `%task_id%`:

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%task_id%', '(\d+)' );
```

And add this code which will replace the `%task_id%` tag in the post permalink:

```
// Replaces %task_id% in the permalink (i.e. $post_link).
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_filter_questions_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
function my_filter_questions_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%task_id%' ) ) {
        $cats = get_the_terms( $post, 'task' );
        $cat_id = 0;

        // If the post was assigned to at least one "task" category.
        if ( $cats && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ) {
            $cat_id = $cats[0]->term_id;
        }
        // Else, /{SLUG}/question/0/{POST SLUG} should work well. =) But of
        // course, all "question" CPT posts should be assigned to *at least*
        // one "task".

        $post_link = str_replace( '%task_id%', $cat_id, $post_link );
    }

    return $post_link;
}
```

The *full* sample code [is available here](https://pastebin.com/sw7bSTTw). :)

**Don't forget to *flush* the rewrite rules!**

It *is* necessary and here's how: Just go to the "Permalink Settings" page. That's all.

But if the rewrite rules were not flushed (you can confirm by visiting the "question" page), then on the "Permalink Settings" page, click on the "Save Changes" button *without* having to make any changes.

**How to get the value of `task_id`**

Use `get_query_var( 'task_id' )`. Example:

```
$task_id = get_query_var( 'task_id' );
$term = get_term( $task_id );
```

---

*PS: I know the question has changed, but I updated this answer because it could help someone else. ;)*

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks a million! Could you kindly provide an example where if the CPT does not have consistent slug format of "{subject}-questions}"... do I use is_front = true in the code ?

Comment: Hi @Atimmy. where did you see the `is_front`? I don't actually know if that's relevant to the WordPress URL rewriting. But if you have "questions" CPT that doesn't end with or doesn't even use *-question* in its key/slug, then there's a way to fix that.

Comment: I've updated the code, so that it doesn't rely on *{subject}-question*. Try it out and let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: The code looks awesome, I will try it out and let you know how things go. Thank you again.   By the way, are you available for hire at all? I might need more WP help in nearby future.

Comment: For the time being, I'm not available for hire. Thanks though, for asking. =) And hopefully the code works for you.

Comment: Hi Sally, are you still too busy for hire?

Comment: Hi Sally, there is one weird problem, when I update the post title, the link does not update, it still use the old post title... any idea how to fix it?  @Sally

Comment: another question is, if I have custom field in my cpt and I wish to use it in my URL format, can do I do that?  Say if I have a custom field with slug "custom-question-id", I  tried this but doesn't work:

   $cp_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom-question-id', true );
  and I put "$cp_id" to both the add_rewrite_rule section and $permalink = ... section...

Comment: Hi Atimmy. Apologize for the late reply. For the post title issue, I think the best way is to manually update the post's slug. (If the slug box doesn't appear, then check the box next to Slug in the Screen Options panel.) In the Quick Edit mode, you could simply empty the Slug field and it would be auto-generated for you.

Comment: For the custom field part, see my [second answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/306993/137402) and try it out, and let me know how it goes. If it works for you, you should un-accept this answer and accept the other one. =)

Comment: I've edited the question... could you kindly assist in a solution ?

Comment: Check the updated answer - the other one, not this.

Comment: hi Sally, it's me again, Thank you for answering my questions a few years ago.

Comment: I am wondering if I have two custom taxonomies setup linked with the CPT. and we need to create a public filter page. how can we do that ?

Say the custom taxonomy slugs are:
(1) "question_difficulties", with terms "simple", "advanced", "pro"
(2) "task", with terms "task1", "task2", "task3", "task4"

How can we make public buttons that allow users to filter the query

Comment: Hi @Atimmy :) So I would love to help you with that filter thing, but could you please post that as a new question? (and btw, I saw the deleted question you posted on this page, so please post it as a separate question instead)

Comment: Hi @Sally CJ, I have post a new question here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/390295/how-to-build-a-achieve-page-for-a-custom-cpt-with-multiple-taxonomy-button-filte

Comment: Hi Sally, I am studying your code once again. Quick question about the Answer 2 (the latest one), if I use "        'slug' => 'english/question/%task_id%', " when registering the CPT, what would the default achieve page for this particular CPT looks like?

Comment: Sorry, I've just got back online today. So what actually did you mean by "achieve page"? I initially thought you misspelled "archive" as "achieve". And if you meant, how would the *permalink* **look** like, then it's `example.com/english/question/123/post-slug` where `123` is the task/term ID. But if you mean the page itself (i.e. the content), then that would depend on your theme/template.