# How to build a achieve page for a custom CPT with multiple taxonomy button filter

Tags: multi-taxonomy-query, rewrite-tag

This is an extended question from
[Permalink for CPT with taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301239/permalink-for-cpt-with-taxonomy)

---

I am building a website that has a CPT and a few custom taxonomies.

Each single CPT post is basically "a question" for student to practice with. I would like to setup a "taxonomy filter page", so user can quickly find the one they are looking for in the right categories.

I am creating a "CPT & Taxonomy filter" page to serve this purpose. Note that the CPT archive url and its custom taxonomy url are all being pointed to the same php template file ("english_speakings-taxonomy-tpl.php").

Now...I have struggling with a few different questions...hoping someone can help.

#### Below is a screenshot of what the page should look like

This is a HTML markup for **custom taxonomy achieve page** ("english_speakings-taxonomy-tpl.php"):
(all the custom taxonomies for this CPT, and the CPT achieve page are being redirected to the same template file, with the help of "template_include" hook)

[image: filter html markup screenshot]

(* The buttons from the above image are just HTML dummy code, they are not being generate from a php function... because I do not know how to do it. )

---

#### Questions

Here are my questions:

- **Q1:** Currently the buttons are just handcoded html markup, I know how to output each taxonomy terms with php, but I am unsure about what goes into each hyperlink ( `<a herf="????">` ).
- **Q2:** I know how to register **custom vars** with WP, but I do not know how to actually put it to work. In another words, how can I connect the registered **custom vars** with my custom taxonomy terms respectively??
- **Q3:** CPT/ CPT Taxonomy Permalink... I am aware that in order to setup a clean URL, I shall be using  "Adding Rewrite Tags"... but I do not understand how to use them, regex and match[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbHJ5.png), match[2] ..these are very confusing to me
- **Q4:** Need advice or suggestion on the URL structure.

---

#### Here's the current setup:

#### ###### Custom Post Type:

English Speaking, with slug name "english_speakings"

###### Custom Taxonomies:

(1) Question Tasks ("english_speaking_tasks"), and its terms: "task1", "task2", "task3"

(2) Difficulties ("english_speaking_difficulties") and its terms: "easy", "advanced", "pro"

(3) Course ("english_speaking_courses") and its terms: "course-a", "course-b", "course-c"

#### Register Custom CPT: English-Speakings

```
register_post_type( 'english-speakings', array(
    'label' => 'English Speaking',
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'english/speaking/%speaking_task%/%course%/',
    ),
    // Other args here.
) );
```

#### Register Custom Taxonomies

I am unsure about the rewrite slug for each taxonomy, as **I am pointing all of them to the same template page, the "CPT & Taxonomy filter page"**.

**Can I put the same slug  ('slug' => 'english/speakings',) for all of them?**

```
// Task
register_taxonomy( 'speaking-task', array( 'english-speakings' ), array(
    'label' => 'Speaking Tasks',
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'english/speakings',
    ),
    // Other args here.
) );


// Difficulties 
register_taxonomy( 'english_speaking_difficulties', array( 'english-speakings' ), array(
    'label' => 'Speaking Tasks',
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'english/speaking/difficulties',
    ),
    // Other args here.
) );



// Course
register_taxonomy( 'english_speaking_courses', array( 'english-speaking' ), array(
    'label' => 'Speaking Tasks',
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'english/speaking/courses',
    ),
    // Other args here.
) );
```

---

```
'slug' => 'english/speaking/%speaking_task%/???????/',
```

###### Question: For the URL format, I need some guidance or suggestion here...

For SEO purpose, I like to setup a Clean URL, but I do not need all the taxonomy names to show up there, and I might have more taxonomies created in the future...

Instead of [https://example.com/{cpt-slug}/{task-slug}/{course-slug}/{difficulty-slug}](https://example.com/%7Bcpt-slug%7D/%7Btask-slug%7D/%7Bcourse-slug%7D/%7Bdifficulty-slug%7D)
(  https://example.com/english/task1/course-a/pro )

The ideal format is:

- [http://example.com/english/{task-slug}/{course-term-id}{difficulties-term-id}](http://example.com/english/%7Btask-slug%7D/%7Bcourse-term-id%7D%7Bdifficulties-term-id%7D)

Example: https://example.com/english/task1/2035 or 20-35 or 20/35
( where 20 and 35 are the term id: course-a("20"), pro("35"))

The above URL should be interpreted as:
example.com/index.php?post_typ=english_speakings&english_speaking_tasks=task1&english_speaking_courses=course-a&english_speaking_difficlties=pro

(Note: The above URL is still on the very same page of the screenshot image of the CPT & Taxonomy filter page, loaded with the template file: "english_speakings-taxonomy-tpl.php" )

When users click into one of the single post, the permalink should be something like: example.com/english/{task}/{post-id}

---

Register the custom var with WP.

I have three taxonomies that need to be functional as filters, so I am going to register them to WP as custom vars:

```
function cpt_english_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'course';
    $vars[] = 'task';
    $vars[] = 'difficulty';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cpt_english_register_query_vars' );
```

Build Query for the CPT Achieve page

(this is part of the "english_speakings-taxonomy-tpl.php" page)

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; //use 'page' if the query is on a static front page
    
    
    $course =  get_query_var( 'course' ) ?: "courseA"; //set default value as "courseA"
    $task = get_query_var('task') ?: "task1"; // default value "task1" 
    $difficulty = get_query_var('difficulty') ?: "easy"; //default value "easy"
    
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'english_speakings',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' =>  20 ,
        'paged' => $paged,
    
         'tax_query' => array(
    
           'relation' => 'AND', 
            
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'english_speaking_tasks',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $task,
            ),
    
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'english_speaking_courses',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $course,
            ),
    
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'english_speaking_difficlties',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $difficulty,
            ),
    
        ),
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And Output the custom Query:

```
<?php

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        $the_query->the_post();
?>

Content ...

<?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); //wp_reset_query();
} else {
    echo '<div class="card-body"><p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p></div>';
}
?>
```

And I am lost from here....

Comment: Can you split your questions into two or more posts? So for example on this post, you could ask about the archive page, and on another page, you could ask about the new CPT permalink structure. Also, what is the actual post type that you used, is it `english_speakings` or `english-speakings`? Same goes with the taxonomies, please ensure they're correct in the question, e.g. is it `english_speaking_courses` or `english_speaking_course` (note the plural vs singular "course")?

Comment: And note that you need to include the post slug or ID in the permalink (structure) so that WordPress knows which post is being requested, hence `http://example.com/english/{task-slug}/{course-term-id}{difficulties-term-id}` won't work - it needs `{post-slug}` or `{post-id}` somewhere. And referring to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbHJ5.png), what is the code you used to output the buttons? Where's your archive page located, e.g. `example.com/my-archive`? Is it a Page (post type of `page`)?

Comment: Hi Sally, (1) Okay, I will split my questions. (2) for the permalink, the reason it did not has a post slug or ID is because they are all redirecting to the cpt archive template.

Comment: Post type used here is: english_speakings. I read somewhere that it should always be plural form for the name. I have edited the questions and make sure they are consistent now, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ I have edited my question, hope it it more easy to understand now. I have tired to separate the questions but in my mind this is one question... I am unsure how do I split them into two. Shall I duplicate my entire question content and re-post with different questions asked?

Comment: "they are all redirecting to the cpt archive template" - so basically, you're actually looking for an answer on how can you achieve a SEO-friendly or "pretty" filter URL, right? And in reply to, "Shall I duplicate my entire question content and re-post with different questions asked?", no, but for example the buttons thing could actually go in a separate question - e.g. "how can I get all terms in a taxonomy and output a button for each term".. So try to focus on one thing, like small tasks in a milestone in a project.

Comment: And as for this: "Can I put the same slug ('slug' => 'english/speakings',) for all of them?" - no, not by default because it will cause a conflict, i.e. WordPress will not know for sure which taxonomy does the queried term belongs in.

Comment: Yes. The main task is to make this filter page functional, and achieve the SEO-friendly URL at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126292/discussion-between-atimmy-and-sally-cj).

Comment: @SallyCJ, would you consider answer one of the questions first and then I will edit my question and re-post another question with the leftover questions. I understand your idea of small tasks in a milestone in a project. But in my mind it is one question I been struggling with for weeks. it's a bit challenging  for me to separate them. I know how to output each term name or term slug using php, the part I am unsure is what is the correct URL that shall be used for each button's hyperlink. Which is also one of the important factor for the filter page to work.