# Custom Post Type Rewrite URL

Tags: posts, customization

So I followed a guide on another post here to add a taxonomy to the post type URL which works BUT it breaks the url's for the pages.

My permalink structure is `%postname%` and my code is as follows:

Post type:

```
 $args = array(
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => null,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
  'rewrite' => array(
   'slug' => '%product_cat%',
   'with_front' => false
  ),
 ); 

 register_post_type( 'kh_products' , $args );
```

Code to modify the slug:

```
function change_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
 $post = get_post($id);  
 if ( is_object( $post ) ){
  $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'kh_product_cat' );
  if ( $terms ) {
   $replaced = $terms[0]->slug;
   return str_replace( '%product_cat%' , $replaced, $post_link );
  }
 }
 return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

If you remove the slug line from the post type, the post type url stops working (as intended) and the page url works but add the line back and the pages url's stop working.

I have tried changing the url slug to %%product_cat%% and that stops the post type url from working.

Removing the filter doesn't do anything so the issue is just with the slug string.

Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Everything looks right. I assume you already flushed the permalinks as well? Also this answer might help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94820/130535

Comment: This is on a clean install of WP so no conflicts that I can see, Clear the permalinks everytime we make a change and doesn't affect it, that link is the initial guide we followed.

Comment: What if you try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108647/130535 essentially its changing the rewrite to slug => '/kh_product/%product_cat%'