# How to change custom categories term links?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, links

I have created "Tour Vacation"(tour-vacation) custom taxonomy and added below terms

- Africa (africa)
- Canada (canada)
- Europe (europe)
- US (us)

I want change this terms links.

Current link is: https://tourjourneys.staging.com/africa/

I want to change it to:
https://tourjourneys.staging.com/vacation-pacakge/africa-tour/

So i have done below code.

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'change_term_link', 10, 3 );
function change_term_link( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
  if ( 'tour-vacation' === $taxonomy ) {
    $url = home_url() . '/vacation-pacakge/' . $term->slug.'-tour';
  }
  return $url;
}
```

The link is changing but it's showing "404 page not found error"

Am i missing anything?

Comment: What are you setting as `rewrite` value when you `register_taxonomy()`?

Comment: please check : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy