# Taxonomy rewrite question

Tags: url-rewriting, taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I have custom post types for dining, lodging, and activities. Each of those custom post types uses a custom taxonomy called region. If, for example, I have a region called "downtown", I would like to be able to show dining option for that region by going to domain.com/downtown/dining. Or show hotels in that region by going to domain.com/downtown/lodging. So, basically, I like to create a rewrite rule to give the structure domain.com/tax-term/cpt-slug to show all the posts for the cpt that have that tax term selected. Any way to do this?

Comment: Looks like it's already [answered here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/94817/63470)

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. In my case, my client doesn't want an overall cpt slug in the url. They want it to start with the slug of each cpt post. e.g. not /region/downtown/, but just /downtown/. In this case, the solution below seems to make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your permalink structure for taxonomy will conflict with default one for pages.

In the case of the address `domain.com/item-one/item-two` how does Wordpress know if it's a page `item-two` with the parent page `item-one` **or** `item-two` is custom post type and `item-one` is term of `region` taxonomy?
The order of rewrite rules will decide, and because rule for your structure will be first, links to child pages (like `domain.com/parent-page/child-page`) will be directed to taxonomy page (*taxonomy*= "region", *term*= "parent-page", *post_type*= "child-page").

There are two ways, of which I would choose the first.

- Add some prefix to your structure e.g. `regions/{term}/{cpt_slug}`
- Generate rewrite rules for all terms (`downtown` and others) from `region` taxonomy (one rule for each term).
  Generating must be repeated after adding and removing the custom taxonomy term.

In both cases, to make rewrite rules work, you have to click **Save** in `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks` or use `flush_rewrite_fules()` (["important note"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage))

---

### Option #1

I used `regions` as url prefix and `region_cpt` as query variable name, you can change them to the ones you prefer.

```
add_action( 'init', 'se333633_rewrite_tags', 10 );
add_action( 'init', 'se333633_rewrite_rules' );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'se333633_pre_get_posts', 30 );

function se333633_rewrite_tags() 
{
     add_rewrite_tag( '%region_cpt%', '([^/]+)' );
}

function se333633_rewrite_rules()
{
     add_rewrite_rule(
         '^regions/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
         'index.php?taxonomy=region&region=$matches[1]&region_cpt=$matches[2]',
         'top'
     );
}

function se333633_pre_get_posts( $query ) 
{
     $cpt_for_region = get_query_var( 'region_cpt', false );
     if ($cpt_from_region !== false && $query->is_main_query() ) 
     {
         $query->query_vars['post_type'] = $cpt_for_region;
     }
}
```

---

### Option #2

In the code from **option #1**, `se333633_rewrite_rules` changes and two new functions are added to refresh rewrite rules after changes in terms.

```
add_action( 'created_term', 'se333633_created_term', 20, 3);
add_action( 'delete_region', 'se333633_region_term_deleted' );

function se333633_rewrite_rules()
{
     $region_terms = get_terms([
         'taxonomy'  => 'region',
         'hide_empty' => false,
         'fields'    => 'id=>slug',
     ]);
     if ( is_array($region_terms) && count($region_terms) )
     {
         foreach( $region_terms as $slug )
         {
             add_rewrite_rule(
                 '^'.$slug.'/([^/]+)/?$',
                 'index.php?taxonomy=region&region='. $slug. '&region_cpt=$matches[1]',
                 'top'
             );
         }
     }
}
function se333633_created_term ( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) 
{
     if ( $taxonomy != 'region')
         return;
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}
function se333633_region_term_deleted( $term )
{
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: I ended up not using exactly what was proposed here, but it was the same concept. I turns out that there are a limited number of known regions that are not expected to change, so I could hardcode the region names in the rewrite rule rather than having to add them programmatically as suggested above. I also combined all the regions into a single OR string so I would only have to use a single rewrite rule. So, instead of the first $slug, I used (downtown|east-side|west-side|uptown) and instead of the second, I used $matches[1] (note that the other $matches[1] changes to $matches[2].