# Add term slug in URL of custom post type details page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have created a custom post type called "movies" and I have added custom taxonomy "Available for " and it contains two terms

1. Rent
2. sales.

Current movie post details page URL

```
movies/avengers-endgame/
```

I want URL Like

```
movies/sales/avengers-endgame/
movies/rent/avengers-endgame/
movies/{%selected term%}avengers-endgame/
```

Anyone, please suggest a possible solution to fix the above issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update below line at where you have register a custom post type using register_post_type function.

**'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies/%cat%')**

To change permalink dynamically of post type you have to add below code in functions.php file :

```
function change_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $id );
    if( $post->post_type == 'movies' ) 
    {
       if ( is_object( $post ) ) {
          # assume that 'available-for' is slug of your taxonomy 
          $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, array('available-for') );
          if ( $terms ) {
             return str_replace( '%cat%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link );
         }
      }
    }
    return   $post_link ;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_link', 1, 3 );

//load the template on the new generated URL otherwise you will get 404's the page



   function generated_rewrite_rules() {
       add_rewrite_rule(
           '^movies/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
           'index.php?post_type=movies&name=$matches[2]',
           'top'
       );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'generated_rewrite_rules' );
```

- domain.com/movies/{%selected term%}/avengers-endgame/

To use Term first, you have change to this.

**'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%cat%/movies')**

```
function change_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $id );
    if( $post->post_type == 'movies' ) 
    {
       if ( is_object( $post ) ) {
          # assume that 'available-for' is slug of your taxonomy 
          $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, array('available-for') );
          if ( $terms ) {
             return str_replace( '%cat%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link );
         }
      }
    }
    return   $post_link ;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_link', 1, 3 );

function movie_cpt_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'available-for',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

$post_type = 'movies';
foreach ($terms as $term) {    

    $rules[ $term->slug .'/movies/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type. '&movies=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';

}
// merge with global rules
$wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'movie_cpt_generating_rule');
```

After that, you need to flush rewrites permalinks, goto the **wp-admin > Settings > permalinks**. just update permalink setting using "Save Changes" button.

it'll return urls like below :

- domain.com/{%selected term%}/movies/avengers-endgame/

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Thanks 
It's work if we add manuall term slug in URL

Comment: this didn't work for you?  i can't get your point. what do you mean manual ?

Comment: Yes it works fine I want to change link like
domain.com/{%selected term%}/movies/avengers-endgame/

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: yes it is possible. i have update the answer. i have add new functions in code. please check then let me know if this helps you or any confution.

Comment: Hello Its working fine with Term first  but I have not added below code
"'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%cat%/movies')" because movies contains sales , rentals or both selected 

so I have created a manual URL and its working fine.

Thanks

Comment: your welcome....

Comment: @Rigal did you downvote my answer ? is this answer not helpfull to you ?

Comment: Yes your answer is very useful for me

Comment: No, I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: okay. but somebody downvoted my answer. don't know why.

Comment: Seems like its not good way to fix url issue that's why someone downvote

where did you find this code?
Can i have reference code link?

Comment: but you can google. everybody give the same suggestions for do it this way. you can find https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy/340301#340301  i have also posted my answer here

Comment: you can take reference from there but you have to apply your logic as per your requirement. so i have made some changes in my previous code to fulfils your requirement.

Comment: Just a note* The above answer does work as expected however it stops pages with a parent page (nested pages) from working and throws a 404 error.