# WordPress Custom Post Type Category Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, urls, rewrite-rules

I was hoping someone could help me. I have done some serious googling but cannot find the answer for this one.

I have a custom post type called tutorials.

I can go to mysite.com/tutorials and get a list of all the tutorials.

I have also created a custom taxonomy called tutorial_categories with the following code:

```
register_taxonomy(
        'tutorial_categories',
        'tutorials',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Tutorial Categories',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Tutorial Category',
                'new_item_name' => "New Tutorial Category"
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'hasArchive' => true
        )
    );
```

How can I create a category page for a tutorial_category, so if someone goes to:

```
mysite.com/tutorials/php/
```

They will get a list of tutorials (custom post type) with the custom taxonomy of PHP.

A member of stackoverflow recommended I take a look at this:

- [Creating WordPress Custom Taxonomy Archives](http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-archives/) - WP-Types.com

But this doesn't work either. I have created the taxonomy-tutorial_categories.php page but I still get page not found.

Comment: Further reading [Adding categories to custom post type in permalink](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/adding-categories-to-custom-post-type-in-permalink)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing everything right, double check the below code and **make sure to go to Permalinks in your dashboard to flush the rewrite rules**.

From [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen#Customize_Permalink_Structure):

> Note: Visiting the Permalinks screen triggers a flush of rewrite rules. There is no need to save just to flush the rewrite rules.

It will work, I tested it using the below code:

**Put the following in your functions.php**:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_posts' );
function create_custom_posts ()
{      
    register_post_type( 'tutorials',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Tutorials' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Tutorial' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array ('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy(
        'tutorial_categories',
        'tutorials',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Tutorial Categories',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Tutorial Category',
                'new_item_name' => "New Tutorial Category"
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'hasArchive' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Create **taxonomy-tutorial_categories.php**, add a taxonomy category called php from the dashboard, and visit {yourwebsite.com}/tutorial_categories/php/. Works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you! I think mostly I was going to the wrong URL. This works a treat, thank you for your fast support!

Comment: Sure thing. Exactly, you don't go to {custom_post_type}/category. It's {taxonomy}/category.