# Use the category name instead of category slug in permalinks

Tags: categories, permalinks, slug, mod-rewrite

How to create a permalink structure which finish by:

```
/category-name/post-name/
```

Instead of:

```
/category-slug/post-name/
```

By default, Wordpress is offering `%category%` tag strucure as "A sanitized version of the category name (category slug field on New/Edit Category panel".

How can I use the category name instead of category slug in permalinks?

**Note** that I dont need the easiest solution of making my slugs equal to my categories names. In fact, customer need to see in the area of edit post : the categories in a specific non-alpahbetical order. So I managed to do this by giving a digital number for the category as a slug and order showing categories by slug in an ASC mode using:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse_53094_sort_get_terms_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse_53094_sort_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) 
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( !is_admin() || ('post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow) ) 
        return $args;

    $args['orderby'] = 'slug';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';

    return $args;
}
```

I think If I dont manage to use `t f` solution, I will look for a code or a plugin that adds meta field for categories and order by this field in ASC mode. Then I will rename my slugs to the same name of categories. What do you think about this approach?

Thank you for your comment

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can't you simply edit your category slugs so that they match your category names?

Comment: I am answering your important question as an Edit note. thank you for your time.

Comment: For hierarchy purposes, **another USEFUL way**: use **Custom_post_types** instead of **Categories**, like here:<br/>
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/how-to-change-permalink-structure-for-custom-post-type-and-its-taxonomies/#167992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test this, but this should do what you want. Put the following in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'new_category_name_rewrite_rule');
function new_category_name_rewrite_rule($rules) {
    $new_rules = array();
    $categories = get_categories();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $cat_name = preg_replace('#\s+#', '-', $category->name);
        $new_rules['/'.$category->slug.'/'] = '/'.urlencode($cat_name).'/';
    }
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
```