# Possible to remove taxonomy from permalink if uncategorized?

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy

I'm working on a client's website who requested that the custom search functionality I'm building out provide a number of 'pretty' permalinks that they can use for ad campaigns.

The post types I'm working with are community, floorplan, and ready-made homes, and they want to be able to have direct links to search results by county and community.

To achieve this, I set up taxonomies that would create nicely formatted URLS such as {county}/{community}, {county}/{community}/{floorplan} {county}/{community}/{ready-made}.

This is all working fine, however it leads to some issues. For example, If you do not specify a county in your search, you will get links like uncategorized/{community} returned in the results.

Is there any way that you can remove uncategorized taxonomy from the URL, but leave the taxonomy in if it exists?

I've figured out how to update the URLs in the search results, however they will lead to 404s if left completely empty because they technically don't exist if you remove the taxonomy from the url. Ideally, I would want them to just redirect to communities/{community} for example, instead of communities/uncategorized/{community}

Comment: Did you find this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294003/custom-post-type-taxonomy-url-structure  Does it help any?

Comment: @mozboz hey, yes thank you I did find that early on! That works great for adding the taxonomies into your permalink structure, but I was running into the issue where all the results from my queries would not know what taxonomy the results contained, so the urls that were returned looked like /uncategorized/uncategorized/{community} and so on.I think it was because I wasn't using a taxonomy template {taxonomy}-taxonomy.php. A standard custom template will not handle results the same way, so I was getting those uncategorized URLs. My bad!