# How can I assign multiple parents to CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, url-rewriting

I have created cpt called product-1, this product qualifies for 2 categories "paints" and "coatings", however I can only select 1 parent for the post. What would be the best way to achieve the following structure:

- mysite.com/products/paints/product-1
- mysite.com/products/coatings/product-1

I want "Product 1" to display under both categories. I have also created taxonomy with the same structure but that doesn't effect the url.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "Paints" and "coatings" should be terms of custom taxonomy, you can assign to CPT as many terms as you want. A few questions about the taxonomy in CPT permalink that may be helpful: [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500), [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817), [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28979),

Comment: I also tried that but then the url is not structured hierarchiecally. The url above only works when I create product-1 and select Paints or Coatings as its parent. If I do it the way you suggested, this is what I get "mysite.com/products/product-1" So there is no "/paints" OR "/coatings".